# Is it possible to replace AMI programmatically in AWS ElasticBeanstalk?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

From the console, I am able to replace the AMI under Configuration > Modify Instances > AMI ID

I'm trying to do this programmatically using AWS CLI but couldn't find any API to do this.

I tried to replace AMI ID from Cloudformation (that EB deploys) to replace ASG and LC, but then EB environment broke.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found it, using this command:

```
aws elasticbeanstalk update-environment --application-name $EBAppName --environment-name $EBEnvName --option-settings Namespace=aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration,OptionName=ImageId,Value=$ImageID
```